# Regular Expression in JS - Match whole word except for optional s at the end

Tags: javascript, regex, string-matching

I am trying to write a regexp that will match a word but will not match an s at the end if one is there (to 'de-pluralize' the word). I can't quite seem to get it to work.

The format of the input is always a number and then a word, such as:
    `1 carrot`

I want to match the word but not with an s at the end. So it would match `carrot` for both `1 carrot` and `4 carrots`.

I have tried a lookahead, like
`/\w+(?=s)/i`
but then it won't match for the singular word. I don't know how to make an 'optional lookahead' if that makes sense.
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `"1 carrot".match(/\d\s(\bcarrot\b)/i)`

Comment: I do not think the current criteria are good: have a look at the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cJ3lR0/2). `1 plus` - how would you know it is Plural?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
/\b\w+?(?=s?$)/m
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kX3aA1/3)

`(?=s?$)` will assert presence of optional `s` before end of input anchor `$`>

Comment: amazing! You have saved a lot of frustration. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The plus makes your match greedy, you want it [lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

```
\w+?(?=s)
```